# Using nested for loop bash

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am writing bash script for  first time . I have to use `nested for loop`. I have an array like this:

```
(foo,bar a,b)
```

There are two elements in the array and each element in array is separated by commas. I want each element in array to split and print each  element. The final result I want is

```
foo
bar
a
b
```

I am using nested for loop as below but I am not getting any response

```
    IFS=','
    echo "class names is::${classNames[@]}" // prints foo,bar a,b
    for ((n=0;n<${#classNames[@]};n++)){
    
    classes=${classNames[n]}
    
    for ((i=0;n<${#classes[@]};i++)){
    
    echo "${eachClass[i]}"
    
    }
    }
```

Comment: `IFS=','` aaaand where does `IFS` count?

Comment: So IFS should be a space or a comma?

Answer (score 2):

You could:

```
arr=(foo,bar a,b)
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
   while IFS=, read -ra arr_in; do
       for j in "${arr_in[@]}"; do
           echo "$j"
       done
   done <<<"$i"
done
```

or like:

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
   readarray -d, -t arr_in < <(printf "%s" "$i")
   for j in "${arr_in[@]}"; do
       echo "$j"
   done
done
```

or just:

```
while IFS=, read -ra arr_in; do
    for j in "${arr_in[@]}"; do
       echo "$j"
    done
done < <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

or even:

```
while IFS=, read -ra arr_in; do
    printf "%s\n" "${arr_in[@]}"
done < <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

but that said:

```
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | tr ',' '\n'
```

will also print the same.

Do not use `{` `}` as loop terminators - it's undocumented very old bash/shell syntax. Use `do..done`.

`classes=...` is a normal variable, not an array, and in such assignment `IFS` does not matter - here the right part of `=` is not word splitted. To assign an array, use braces `classes=(${classNames[n]})`.

You could just split the values on spaces and comma with IFS:

```
IFS=', ' read -ra arr <<<"${arr[*]}"
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

or even like:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
    echo "$i"
done < <(IFS=', '; printf "%s\n" ${arr[*]})
```

Answer (score 1):

... or like this

```
for item in "${arr[@]}"; {
    sub=(${item//,/ })
    echo "item1=${sub[0]}"
    echo "item2=${sub[1]}"
}
```

with `read`

```
for item in "${arr[@]}"; {
    read i1 i2 <<< ${item//,/ }
    echo "item1=$i1"
    echo "item2=$i2"
}
```

The trick is that we switch ',' to ' '(space) via this bash syntax `${item//,/ }`(${var_name//pattern/replacement}) this is called variable substitution. And this one `<<<` is used to read directly from var.

Comment: can you please explain what is role of //,/  and <<< in bash and what are they called in bash.

Answer (score 0):

A practical one-liner solution without using an apparent loop is

```
(IFS=', '; printf '%s\n' ${classNames[*]})
```

It runs in a subshell not to mess up with current shell's `IFS`.